# Capitalising first letter of each word in section headings using book class

Tags: capitalization

I would like to convert the fist letter of each word in all my section headings to capitals automatically. Is it possible?

ie

`\section{This is my first section}`

**Section 1. This Is My First Section**

Comment: have you seen [Command to uppercase the first letter of each word in a sentence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7992)

Comment: Similar problem: [How to define a command that bolds the first letter of each word in the input argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94367)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any problems with this approach to making the titlecaps automatic for all sections, but it works for the example given.  Check the `titlecaps` documentation for quirks on how to handle different kinds of non-standard text in its argument.

Note how it is able to handle an "exluded words" list, font styles, fontsize changes, as well as diacritics and national symbols like `\ae`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\let\svsection\section
\def\section#1{\svsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\section{This is my first section}

Tah dah  But if you didn't like ``my,'' ``for,'' or ``an'' capitalized, except as the first word:

\Addlcwords{my for an}

\section{for an \ae ncore, my \textit{section} for \small \c consideration}

done.
\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE:  I did find that the section redefinition above will break `\tableofcontents` unless care is taken.  If that is a necessary ingredient of your work, then this approach below will work.  Renewing the `\def` of `\section` must occur after the `\tableofcontents`.  Also, the `\Addlcwords` must occur before the `\tableofcontents`.  Furthermore, fontsize changes in a section heading will also break the `\tableofcontents`, so I have removed them from this example.

EDITED to handle optional arguments in `\section`, as shown in section 3 below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\let\svsection\section
\Addlcwords{is for an of}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand\section[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \svsection{\titlecap{#2}}%
  \else%
    \svsection[\titlecap{#1}]{\titlecap{#2}}%
  \fi%
}
\section{This is my first section}

Tah dah  But if you didn't like ``my,'' ``for,'' or ``an'' capitalized, except as the first word:


\section{for an \ae ncore, my \textit{section} for \c consideration}

\section[table of contents title]{document title}

done.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! How would I change the \section macro in the preamble to include `\titlecap` for all my section headings. That is to say I have written my entire document but fancy making the first letters of my sections capitalised retrospectively.

Comment: @HCAI Perhaps the revised answer will help.

Comment: Superb Thank You! Now I can have a play around with this and see what looks good.

Comment: @HCAl Please see UPDATE, regarding `\tableofcontents`

Comment: Using `\xspace` inside a section headers will result a compilation failures.

Comment: How to use for `\chapter{long}` and `\chapter[short]{long}`? How to renew both commands?

Comment: @JackMiller  I have edited my second example (using `\section`, since `article` has no `\chapter`) to show how optional arguments can be handled.

Comment: Thanks, @all: So for \chapter: First: `\let\svchapter\chapter`, then `\renewcommand{\chapter}[2][\relax]{ \ifx\relax#1 \svchapter{\titlecap{#2}} \else \svchapter[\titlecap{#1}]{\titlecap{#2}} \fi }`

Comment: @JackMiller That is correct.  Best wishes!

Answer (score 2):

Here another working example just like Steven's. This one includes `\chapter` as well. Includes a workaround for problems when creating PDF bookmark and another workaround for problems when creating the bibliography (the comments below).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\let\svchapter\chapter
\let\svsection\section
\let\svsubsection\subsection
\let\svsubsubsection\subsubsection
\Addlcwords{is for an of}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{First chapter}

    %CAPS FOR CHAPTER HEADERS
    \renewcommand{\chapter}[2][\relax]{%
        \ifx\relax#1%
        %\texorpdfstring FIXES LATEX WARNING. PROBLEM: PDF BOOKMARKS ARE NOT CAPITALIZED
        \svchapter{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \else%
        \svchapter[\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#1}}{#1}]{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \fi%
    }

    %CAPS FOR SECTION HEADERS
    \renewcommand{\section}[2][\relax]{%
        \ifx\relax#1%
        \svsection{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \else%
        \svsection[\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#1}}{#1}]{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \fi%
    }   
    \renewcommand{\subsection}[2][\relax]{%
        \ifx\relax#1%
        \svsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \else%
        \svsubsection[\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#1}}{#1}]{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \fi%
    }   
    \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[2][\relax]{%
        \ifx\relax#1%
        \svsubsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \else%
        \svsubsubsection[\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#1}}{#1}]{\texorpdfstring{\titlecap{#2}}{#2}}%
        \fi%
    }   

    \section{This is my first section}

    Cite: \cite{lamport94}


    \section{for an \ae ncore, my \textit{section} for \c consideration}

    \subsection[table of contents title]{document title}

    done.

    %RE-SET CHAPTER COMMAND. OTHERWISE BIBLIOGRAPHY WILL BREAK.
    \renewcommand{\chapter}{\svchapter}

    \begin{thebibliography}{9}

        \bibitem{lamport94}
        Leslie Lamport,
        \emph{\LaTeX: a document preparation system},
        Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
        2nd edition,
        1994.

    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative should you wish to have unnumbered (starred) sections as part of the document, you can use the following

```
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\let\svsection\section
\DeclareDocumentCommand\section{ s m }{% s = star, m = mandatory arg
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \svsection*{\titlecap{#2}}
   }{%
     \svsection{\titlecap{#2}}
   }%
}
```

Note: If you are doing it on all levels you need to start with subsubsection and work towards the section. Going the other way seems to give me errors.