# Automatic Capitalization of sectioning headings?

Tags: sectioning, capitalization

Is there anyway to make LaTeX automatically capitalize sectioning headings?

That is, I would like this to generate a capitalized headline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{This should be in title case.}
But it isn't.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does Capitalization means? `This Should Be In Title Case.` or `THIS SHOULD …`? Related: [Capitalising first letter of each word in section headings using book class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120718)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution, using any additional package, it to modify the `\section`, `\subsection` etc. macros. It can be done fairly easily with the following

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
             {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
             {2.3ex \@plus .2ex}%
             {\normalfont\Large\scshape\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
             {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
             {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
             {\normalfont\large\scshape\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{2}{\z@}%
             {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
             {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
             {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

The title of the section, subection and subsubsection will then be in small caps.

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly good solution as you'd have to change the hardcoded dimensions almost any time you're using a different document class/document layout.

Comment: In fact, this is the proper way to do it, since it doesn't require packages not part of the standard distribution. Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: Would you have a MWE?

Comment: @NBR, where should I put a dot if I want a dot following the section title? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You'd need to dive into the internals of TeX and modify section count format (`\@seccntformat`) command, as explained in the [TeX FAQ](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-seccntfmt). The first example is actually exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 16):

[`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) provides easy hooks into sectional units. `\MakeUppercase` turns the title into UPPERCASE, while `\titlecap` (from [`titlecaps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps)) turns it into Title Case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
\usepackage{titlecaps}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\sectionfont{\MakeUppercase}
\section{This should be in upper case}
It is!
\sectionfont{\titlecap}
\section{This should be in title case}
It is!
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to make the title in the table of content print with the same style as in the body?

Comment: @Mr.Ree: I don't understand... can you elaborate (or ask a new question)?

Comment: @Werner For example, the section title "This should be in upper case" in the table of content is different from "THIS SHOULD BE IN UPPER CASE" in the body. How to make both of them be uppercase? Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Ree: Consider [this paste](http://pastebin.com/mhLP6knQ). It uses [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to intercept and manipulate the arguments passed to `\section` - inserting `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: but "In" should not be capitalized ? isn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `hyperref`, `\MakeUppercase` will break some ToC hyperrefs. You can use latex3 features as an alternative to `\MakeUppercase`, you'll just need to redefine `\section`. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{ % Capitalize section headings
    % \text_uppercase will replace \tl_upper_case in later l3token version
    \tl_set:Nx\section_upper{\cs_if_exist:NTF{\text_uppercase:n}
        {\text_uppercase:n{#3}}{\tl_upper_case:n{#3}}}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\oldsection*{\section_upper}}
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
            {\oldsection{\section_upper}}
            {\oldsection[#2]{\section_upper}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
% Always capitalize section headings in ToC (tex.stackexchange.com/a/156917)
\let\@oldcontentsline\contentsline
\def\contentsline#1#2{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\l@section
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\@oldcontentsline{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}%
    {\@oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{this should be in upper case}
It is!
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this for title case?