# Why doesn't this code combining \foreach with \newtheorem work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems, foreach

Here is an example document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]
\foreach \x in                                         % 1
    {conjecture, definition, example}                  % 2
    {\newtheorem{\x}[baseTheorem]{\MakeUppercase{\x}}} % 3

\begin{document}

\section{Even numbers}

\begin{definition}
    A number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ is zero.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    $2$ and $0$ are both even numbers.
\end{example}

\begin{conjecture}
    The sum of two even numbers is again an even number.
\end{conjecture}

\end{document}
```

This document does not compile. It produces the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \x 

l.16    A
          number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ i...
```

However, if the lines numbered 1, 2 and 3 are replaced with the following lines...

```
\newtheorem{conjecture}[baseTheorem]{\MakeUppercase{conjecture}}
\newtheorem{definition}[baseTheorem]{\MakeUppercase{definition}}
\newtheorem{example}[baseTheorem]{\MakeUppercase{example}}
```

... then the document does compile, and looks as I expect. (What I really want is to capitalise the first letter of "Conjecture" etc., not the entire word, but this is a separate problem.)

Additionally, if `\x` is changed to `\t` in the original versions of lines 1 and 3, a different error message is obtained:

```
! Argument of \UseTextAccent has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.16     A
           number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ ...
```

I reasoned that the issue might be that the third argument of `\newtheorem` was being recorded verbatim and only evaluated when it comes time to typeset an individual theorem environment. I tried the following:

```
\foreach \x in
    {conjecture, definition, example}
    {\def\uppercased\MakeUppercase{\x} \newtheorem{\x}[baseTheorem]{\uppercased}}
```

But it did not get around the problem:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \uppercased 

l.16     A
           number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ ...
```

What can I do?

Comment: For the capitalization side note, `\usepackage{titlecaps}` and replace each instance of `\MakeUppercase{}` with `\titlecap{}`.

Comment: For the capitalization problem see: [Command to uppercase the first letter of each word in a sentence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7992); [How to define a command that bolds the first letter of each word in the input argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94367); [Capitalising first letter of each word in section headings using book class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120718)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The commands in the final argument of `\newtheorem` are expanded as each theorem is set not at the point of definition, so each theorem tries to use the command `\x` in its title, long after your loop has finished. You need to change the order of evaluation, for example this works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]
\foreach \x in                                         % 1
    {conjecture, definition, example}                  % 2
    {\edef\tmp{\noexpand\newtheorem{\x}[baseTheorem]{\noexpand\MakeUppercase{\x}}}\tmp} % 3

\begin{document}

\section{Even numbers}

\begin{definition}
    A number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ is zero.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    $2$ and $0$ are both even numbers.
\end{example}

\begin{conjecture}
    The sum of two even numbers is again an even number.
\end{conjecture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

While [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) has given the technical reasons for your problem (`\x` is expanded to late) in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133601/16595), you can also use the `.list` handler that uses `\foreach` internally but

- doesn’t group its content (not a problem here because `\newtheorem` defines the environments globally anyway) and
- can be used with the already expanded content as `#1` (rather than as a macro sequence).

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]

\pgfkeys{/utils/my Foreach/.code={\newtheorem{#1}[baseTheorem]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}},
         /utils/my Foreach/.list={conjecture, definition, example}}

\begin{document}
\section{Even numbers}

\begin{definition}
    A number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ is zero.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    $2$ and $0$ are both even numbers.
\end{example}

\begin{conjecture}
    The sum of two even numbers is again an even number.
\end{conjecture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Ah well you'd have to know something about pgf to give this answer:-)

Answer (score 6):

As David has already explained, you need to get the strings, not `\x` which expands to the strings. It's easy with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% provide a "user interface"
\cs_set_eq:NN \Foreach \clist_map_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]
\Foreach{conjecture, definition, example}
  {\newtheorem{#1}[baseTheorem]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Even numbers}

\begin{definition}
    A number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ is zero.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    $2$ and $0$ are both even numbers.
\end{example}

\begin{conjecture}
    The sum of two even numbers is again an even number.
\end{conjecture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Ah well you'd have to know something about pgf to give this answer:-) s/pgf/latex3/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `s/pgf/any other loop-providing package/`

Answer (score 3):

*(edit) 2017: since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)` one needs here `\usepackage{xinttools}`. Code updated for that to replace `\usepackage{xint}` of initial answer.*

The reason was explained by David, here is an alternative to using `pgffor`, with the (expandable) utility `\xintApplyUnbraced` of package [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) (yes I do some shameless constant advertising of it here). Presumably some future package release will have more tools and more user-friendly syntax, such as using comma separated list of values.

The `\Action` macro is defined starting with a space: this is done to stop `\xintApplyUnbraced` which always tries to expand things; the space is gobbled, and `\xintApplyUnbraced` will be happy. Then, when all the three `\newtheorem` statements have been prepared, and only then, they are executed.

Note that `\xintApplyUnbraced` is completely expandable and this can help in some contexts.

For each use of `\xintApplyUnbraced` one needs some `\Action` macro, there is no reserved name for it, but a document can use again and again an `\Action` with each time a new definition. I use `\def` rather than  `\newcommand` because `\Action` is more of a low-level helper thing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]

% space at the start could be removed, but in some other situations
% it has its use. It means: don't execute the following code until
% all elements from the initial list have been fed to \Action

\def\Action #1{ \newtheorem{#1}[baseTheorem]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\xintApplyUnbraced\Action{{conjecture}{definition}{example}} 

\begin{document}

\section{Even numbers}

\begin{definition}
    A number is called \emph{even} if its remainder on division by $2$ is zero.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
    $2$ and $0$ are both even numbers.
\end{example}

\begin{conjecture}
    The sum of two even numbers is again an even number.
\end{conjecture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: why-doesnt-foreach-etc]