# Why does cleveref's \crefname command have no effect when it appears within a \foreach?

Tags: cross-referencing, foreach, cleveref

This question follows on from [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133598/why-doesnt-this-code-combining-foreach-with-newtheorem-work), which I asked a few weeks ago. I have since discovered the cleveref package, and I would like to use it for ease in referring to theorem-like environments without having to remember whether a given statement was a theorem, a lemma, a proposition, etc.

Here is a small example document. When I compile this document, the final line of text begins "Here are some references to ?? 1.1, ?? 1.2 and theorem 1.3." The attempt to use `\crefname` to set reference names (I'm not up on the terminology) for the different environments is not working. However, if the line marked with `% (*)` is uncommented, the second "??" will become "toybox". So it is something to do with being in a `\foreach`. But I can't find a way to make it work. It is as though the invocation of `\crefname` is totally ignored within the `\foreach`. Why does this happen?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\def\myTheoremEnvironments{%
    theorem/theorems,%
    cobblestone/cobblestones,%
    toybox/toyboxes%
}

\usepackage{tikz, titlecaps, cleveref}

% Number all definition, theorem, etc. environments using the same counter.
% Start counting again at the start of each section.
% Style these environments using LaTeX's "definition" style.
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]
\foreach \x/\y in \myTheoremEnvironments {
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\newtheorem{\x}[baseTheorem]{\noexpand\titlecap{\x}}}\tmp
    \crefname{\x}{\x}{\y}
}

%\crefname{toybox}{toybox}{toyboxes} % (*)

\begin{document}

\section{Hello, and welcome to my document.}

\begin{cobblestone}
    \label{csref}
    Hello. I am an ``cobblestone'' environment.
\end{cobblestone}

\begin{toybox}
    \label{tbref}
    I am a ``toybox'' environment. What a strange name that is for an environment.
\end{toybox}

\begin{theorem}
    \label{thmref}
    People trying to do strange things with ``foreach'' should expect trouble.
\end{theorem}

Here are some references to \cref{csref}, \cref{tbref} and \cref{thmref}.
I could have tried using just one call to ``cref'' here,
but it's best not to run before you can walk.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The main problem is the usual one: `\foreach` executes its cycles in a group and `\crefname` only does local assignments.

Comment: The author of the `cleveref` package, @TobyCubitt, appears now to be active on this StackExchange.

Comment: I couldn't remember if there was a good reason for making `\crefname` do local assignments. Luckily, my former and smarter self kindly left an explanation in the manual (implementation section). To quote myself: "`\crefname` *must* *not* create global definitions, or else it will break `babel`'s `\otherlanguage` and `\foreignlanguage` commands." I no longer recall why this will break `babel`, but presumably the answer's somewhere in the `babel` manual/code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big problem is that `\foreach` does each cycle inside a group; while `\newtheorem` definitions are global, `\crefname` definitions aren't.

I suggest a perhaps more user-friendly interface.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{titlecaps, cleveref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachpair}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \hammerite_foreachpair:on { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \hammerite_foreachpair:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \hammerite_foreachpair:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set:Npn \__hammerite_temp:nn ##1 ##2 { #2 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \__hammerite_dopair:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__hammerite_dopair:n #1
 {
  \__hammerite_dopair:wn #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__hammerite_dopair:wn #1/#2 \q_stop
 {
  \__hammerite_temp:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hammerite_foreachpair:nn { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Number all definition, theorem, etc. environments using the same counter.
% Start counting again at the start of each section.
% Style these environments using LaTeX's "definition" style.

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]

\foreachpair
 {
  theorem/theorems,
  cobblestone/cobblestones,
  toybox/toyboxes,
 }
 {
  \newtheorem{#1}[baseTheorem]{\titlecap{#1}}
  \crefname{#1}{#1}{#2}
 }

\begin{document}

\section{Hello, and welcome to my document.}

\begin{cobblestone}\label{csref}
Hello. I am an ``cobblestone'' environment.
\end{cobblestone}

\begin{toybox}\label{tbref}
I am a ``toybox'' environment. What a strange name that is for an environment.
\end{toybox}

\begin{theorem}\label{thmref}
People trying to do strange things with ``foreach'' should expect trouble.
\end{theorem}

Here are some references to \cref{csref}, \cref{tbref} and \cref{thmref}.
I could have tried using just one call to ``cref'' here,
but it's best not to run before you can walk.

\end{document}
```

As you see, the second argument of `\foreachpair` is a comma separated list of items of the form `<item-a>/<item-b>`; the second argument is like a command definition, at each cycle `<item-a>` is substituted for `#1` and `<item-b>` is substituted for `#2`.

There's also an alternative way of calling it

```
\newcommand\myTheoremEnvironments{
  theorem/theorems,
  cobblestone/cobblestones,
  toybox/toyboxes
}

\foreachpair* \myTheoremEnvironments
 {
  \newtheorem{#1}[baseTheorem]{\titlecap{#1}}
  \crefname{#1}{#1}{#2}
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\foreach` does each iteration in a group and furthermore `\crefname` does not expand its second argument.

One can circumvent these problems using `\xintForpair` from package [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}


\usepackage{tikz, titlecaps, cleveref}

% Number all definition, theorem, etc. environments using the same counter.
% Start counting again at the start of each section.
% Style these environments using LaTeX's "definition" style.
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]

% Does not work: 
% \def\myTheoremEnvironments{%
%     theorem/theorems,%
%     cobblestone/cobblestones,%
%     toybox/toyboxes%
% }
% \foreach \x/\y in \myTheoremEnvironments {
%     \edef\tmp{\noexpand\newtheorem{\x}[baseTheorem]{\noexpand\titlecap{\x}}}\tmp
%     \crefname{\x}{\x}{\y}
% }

% alternative using \xintForpair:

\usepackage{xinttools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xint

\xintForpair #1#2 in 
{% spaces around commas or like the end of lines here, 
 % or around parentheses are removed automatically
   (theorem,theorems),
   (cobblestone,cobblestones),
   (toybox,toyboxes)
}
\do
{%  (spaces significant but do not matter)
    \newtheorem{#1}[baseTheorem]{\titlecap{#1}}
    \crefname{#1}{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Hello, and welcome to my document.}

\begin{cobblestone}
    \label{csref}
    Hello. I am an ``cobblestone'' environment.
\end{cobblestone}

\begin{toybox}
    \label{tbref}
    I am a ``toybox'' environment. What a strange name that is for an environment.
\end{toybox}

\begin{theorem}
    \label{thmref}
    People trying to do strange things with ``foreach'' should expect trouble.
\end{theorem}

Here are some references to \cref{csref}, \cref{tbref} and \cref{thmref}.
I could have tried using just one call to ``cref'' here,
but it's best not to run before you can walk.

\end{document}
```

> [image: loops with crefname]

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion of the xint loop and I considered using this. It seems like this functionality has only very recently (like, in the last month) been added to xint. The alternative won out in part because I don't have to update my LaTeX installation!

Comment: @Hammerite yes it is a recent addition. I completely understand your reasons for going with `egreg`'s answer.B

Answer (score 1):

> [Y]ou can […] use the `.list` handler that uses `\foreach` internally but
>
> - doesn’t group its content […] and
> - can be used with the already expanded content as `#1` (rather than as a macro sequence).

Using

```
\pgfkeys{/utils/my Foreach/.code args={#1/#2}{\newtheorem{#1}[baseTheorem]{\titlecap{#1}}%
                                              \crefname{#1}{#1}{#2}},
         /utils/my Foreach/.list/.expand once=\myTheoremEnvironments}
```

gives

[image]