# What is going wrong with this attempt to use \global?

Tags: macros

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145330/why-does-cleverefs-crefname-command-have-no-effect-when-it-appears-within-a-f) I have already been given a sophisticated way of achieving what I set out to do. This question is not a "how do I do this" question - I already have an answer to that - it is a "explain for me what is the flaw in the approach I attempted" question.

The original problem was that the `\crefname` macro provided by the cleveref package was not having any effect within a `\foreach`. It was pointed out by jfbu (in an answer) and egreg (in a comment) that the problem was that `\crefname` has an effect only locally, and the changes are discarded at the end of every loop iteration. In the time before egreg posted an answer providing a solution, it occurred to me to use the `\foreach` to build a command to perform the `\crefname` changes, then call that command after the loop had ended. I used the `\global` macro to make the changes global. Unfortunately, the `\global` causes error messages to appear, and I don't know why. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\def\myTheoremEnvironments{%
    theorem/theorems,%
    cobblestone/cobblestones,%
    toybox/toyboxes%
}

\usepackage{tikz, titlecaps, cleveref}

% Number all definition, theorem, etc. environments using the same counter.
% Start counting again at the start of each section.
% Style these environments using LaTeX's "definition" style.
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{baseTheorem}{Base Theorem}[section]
\def\mycrefnamecommands{}
\foreach \x/\y in \myTheoremEnvironments {
    \edef\tmp{\noexpand\newtheorem{\x}[baseTheorem]{\noexpand\titlecap{\x}}}\tmp
    \global\edef\mycrefnamecommands{\mycrefnamecommands\noexpand\crefname{\x}{\x}{\y}}
}
\mycrefnamecommands

\begin{document}

\section{Hello, and welcome to my document.}

\begin{cobblestone}
    \label{csref}
    Hello. I am an ``cobblestone'' environment.
\end{cobblestone}

\begin{toybox}
    \label{tbref}
    I am a ``toybox'' environment. What a strange name that is for an environment.
\end{toybox}

\begin{theorem}
    \label{thmref}
    People trying to do strange things with ``foreach'' should expect trouble.
\end{theorem}

Here are some references to \cref{csref}, \cref{tbref} and \cref{thmref}.
I could have tried using just one call to ``cref'' here,
but it's best not to run before you can walk.

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message. I tried googling it, but I don't see any particularly useful results.

```
! Argument of \@ynthm has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.66 }
```

Comment: `\gdef` is global `\def`, `\xdef` is global `\edef`

Comment: I tried changing the `\global\edef` to `\xdef`, it results in the same error message.

Comment: This is a good attempt (weren't it for the small glitch). I'd prefer my expl3 solution, though. `;-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to remember that `\edef` expands *all the way*, but `\noexpand` only inhibits expansion once. So after the first cycle the replacement text of `\mycrefnamecommands` is

```
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
```

and at the second cycle `\edef` will try to expand `\crefname`, causing a disaster.

You have to be careful and only expand *once* `\mycrefnamecommands` in the various steps. This can be done in two ways:

```
\toks0=\expandafter{\mycrefnamecommands}%
\xdef\mycrefnamecommands{\the\toks0 \noexpand\crefname{\x}{\x}{\y}%
```

using the fact that token lists resulting from `\the\toks0` is not further expanded by `\edef` (`\xdef` is the same as `\global\edef`).

Another way, that exploits e-TeX extensions (which are available in LaTeX) is

```
\xdef\mycrefnamecommands{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter{\mycrefnamecommands}%
  \noexpand\crefname{\x}{\x}{\y}%
}%
```

which essentially does the same as above, but in only one step.

A different strategy could be

```
\def\mycrefnamecommands{}
\foreach \x/\y in \myTheoremEnvironments {
  \let\crefname\relax
  \edef\tmp{\noexpand\newtheorem{\x}[baseTheorem]{\noexpand\titlecap{\x}}}\tmp
  \xdef\mycrefnamecommands{\mycrefnamecommands\crefname{\x}{\x}{\y}}
}
\mycrefnamecommands
```

In the `\foreach` cycle we set `\crefname` equal to `\relax`, so it becomes unexpandable and so it will not be interpreted in any way by `\xdef`; however, at the end of `\foreach`, `\crefname` will have its original meaning back, hence at the time of the execution of the final `\mycrefnamecommands` macro it will do its job regularly.

Comment: You have so many ideas on how to do things. I feel like I am getting better at understanding TeX's macro expansion behaviour, but I have a long way to go before I understand it like you :)

Comment: @Hammerite Well, you were a baby when I started using TeX. ;-)

Comment: @Hammerite Here are some tools that helped me when I was getting started: Put `\errorcontextlines=100` at the start of the file to get a better idea where a macro goes bad (not much help for this one). Put `\show\mycrefnamecommands` just before and after the `global\edef` is applied to it. You can thus see just what TeX has done to it. On the second pass you will see that the `\noexpand` was not retained and then the error message from the expansion of `\crefname`.