# Extract first letter of each word in a sentence

Tags: macros, acronyms, latex3, token-lists

I don't know if already exists a question like this, but after 20 minutes I haven't found one.

There are similar ones, like [How to define a command that bolds the first letter of each word in the input argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94367/how-to-define-a-command-that-bolds-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-the-input-ar), but it's not the same as mine.

I'm looking for a command `\shortenthis{…}` which extracts the first letter of each word in the command. `\shortenthis{Leonard Euler}` will give us `LE`. In case of `\shortenthis{Pierre de Fermat}` it should give `PdF`.

The idea is to shorten names.

I guess this is “easy” with LaTeX3 (although I'm a newbie, I looked in the documentation, and examples in this site, and couldn't do it), but any solution would be accepted.

Comment: Already found an answer. If someone marks this as a duplicate, will delete it. If not, may be it's good for the community to have it here.

Comment: Which question do you think this is a duplicate of?

Comment: I don't know, but my memory keeps saying that I have already seen something like this.

Comment: Why don't you use some `acronym` facility instead of re-inventing things?

Comment: I have an answer ready, shoot if you still need it. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Already posted mine (almost a copy of cgnieder solution in the question I linked). But if you have something post it, I will accept any other answer but mine.

Comment: @HarishKumar I don't know. I thought it was more advanced and I don't require anything else than I posted. May be it's easier, but I thought it wasn't worth it learning how to use it.

Comment: No you are wrong. :) It is easy an worthy spending time on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost a copy of cgnieder's solution in the link I posted.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\shortenthis{ m }
    {
        \shorten_this:n { #1 }
    }

\seq_new:N \l_shorten_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shorten_this:n #1
    {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_shorten_seq { ~ } { #1 }
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_shorten_seq
            {
                \tl_head:n { ##1 }
            }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\shortenthis{Pierre de Fermat}
\shortenthis{Leonard Euler}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if the text is in a variable, e.g. `\newcommand{\abc}{Abc}` `\shortenthis{\abc}` outputs "Abc".

Comment: Add `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \shorten_this:n { V, o, x, e }` and use any of the variants in the definition of `\shortenthis`, i.e. `\shorten_this:V #1` (this only works for single tokens in the argument, like `\abc`), `\shorten_this:o { #1 }` (this may be the more generic), `\shorten_this:x { #1 }` (this expands everything), or `\shorten_this:e { #1 }` this expands everything too.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer, the macro `\getargsC` extracts each word of the argument into the macros `\argi`, `\argii`, etc.  Then I set up a loop to grab the first letter of each word with a simple `\def`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{index}\setcounter{index}{0}
\def\firstletters#1{%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \edef\nextword{\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\getfirst\nextword\relax%
  }%
}
\def\getfirst#1#2\relax{#1}
\begin{document}
\firstletters{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System.}
\end{document}
```

[image]