# Extract first letter of each word, also after a special character like a dash

Tags: macros, acronyms, latex3

This question based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163053/extract-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence).

Found letter missing when it occurs next to dash, as per the below MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{index}\setcounter{index}{0}
\def\firstletters#1{%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \edef\nextword{\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\getfirst\nextword\relax%
  }%
}
\def\getfirst#1#2\relax{#1}
\begin{document}
\firstletters{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System. This-Test. for sample. This T.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package provides `\DTLinitials`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool-base}

\begin{document}

\DTLinitials{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System.
This-Test. for sample. This T.}

\end{document}
```

[image: T.i.a.t.o.t.E.B.S.T.-T.f.s.T.T.]

This automatically inserts a period after each initial, but that can be prevented by redefining `\DTLafterinitials`, `\DTLbetweeninitials` and `\DTLafterinitialbeforehyphen` to do nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool-base}

\renewcommand*{\DTLbetweeninitials}{}
\renewcommand*{\DTLafterinitials}{}
\renewcommand*{\DTLafterinitialbeforehyphen}{}

\begin{document}

\DTLinitials{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System.
This-Test. for sample. This T.}

\end{document}
```

[image: TiatotEBST-TfsTT]

If you need the initials in an expandable context, you first need to use `\DTLstoreinitials`, which will save the initials in the command provided in the second argument:

```
\DTLstoreinitials{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System.
This-Test. for sample. This T.}{\initials}

\initials
```

Edit: if you also want to remove the hyphen from the initials, just redefine `\DTLinitialhyphen` to do nothing as well:

```
\renewcommand*{\DTLinitialhyphen}{}
```

Edit2: Note that `\DTLinitials` is designed primarily for names (its original purpose was for use with the abbreviated bibliography style provided by `databib`) so it assumes its argument is a series of letters separated by spaces or hyphens. Additionally from the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf):

> Be careful if the initial letter has an accent. The accented letter
>   needs to be placed in a group, if you want the initial to also have an
>   accent, otherwise the accent command will be ignored.

So, as per your comment below:

```
\DTLinitials{{\"{O}}zg\"{u}r}
```

Or use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with UTF-8 characters. This is similar to the [limitations on `\makefirstuc` (from `mfirstuc`)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mfirstuc/mfirstuc-manual.html#sec:utf8)

Also from the `datatool` manual:

> In fact, any command which appears at the start of the name that is
>   not enclosed in a group will be ignored.

This means that, say

```
\DTLinitials{\MakeUppercase{m}ary ann}
```

will produce m.a. not M.a.

Comment: Your method doesn't appear to notice that the very first character of the string need not be a letter.

Comment: `\DTLinitials{\"{O}zg\"{u}r}` produces output as `O.` & 
`\DTLinitials{{\"{O}}zg\"{u}r}` produces the proper output `Ö`... Any advice on this...

Comment: @Mico Yes, this is because `\DTLinitials` is intended primarily for names so it assumes the string is in the form of a name.

Comment: @KumareshPS I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Excellent!!!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution based  on classical TeX only:

```
\def\firstletters{\bgroup \catcode`-=10 \catcode`(=10 \filA}
\def\filA#1{\filB#1 {\end} }
\def\filB#1#2 {\ifx\end#1\egroup \else#1\expandafter\filB\fi} 

\firstletters{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System. 
   This-Test. for sample (per se). This T.}

\bye
```

Comment: I like this simplicity!  Is there a way to preserve specific other characters?  For example, given the input: "Hello, you wonderful world!"  I would like the output: "H, yww!" (preserving the ',' and the '!')

Comment: Also, I am much less familiar with TeX than with LaTeX, so could you offer a little explanation of what your solution is doing? (I get the general idea of \def and #1#2, but don't understand the \bgroup, \egroup, and \catcode)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \firstletters { m } { \kumaresh_firstletters:n { #1 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kumaresh_firstletters:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { ~ }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \tl_head:n { ##1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstletters{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System. This-Test. for sample. This T.}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's a version that copes with traditional TeX accents (I did not put the whole list, just a few, add anything you want to the definition). This is probably on the limit of complexity while using predefined variables from expl3, it's recommended to define your own variables rather than use the default `tmpa`, etc.

Also, this version copes in a basic way with functions of the type `\emph{words here}` and will convert that to `\emph{wh}`. And also with `[brackets and (parenthesis)]` (and whatever you add) and it will convert that to `bap`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \firstletters { m } { \kumaresh_firstletters:n { #1 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kumaresh_firstletters:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { ~ } % here we convert dashes into spaces for our function
  \tl_map_inline:nn { [( } % here we remove certain symbols (and whatever you add) so that it doesn't interfere
   { \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 } }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \kumaresh_firstletters_head:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:NnTF { NV }
\tl_const:Nn \c_kumaresh_accents_tl
 { \^ \" \' \` \H \. \d \~ \v } % here should be all accents
\tl_new:N \g_kumaresh_fl_exceptions_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g_kumaresh_fl_exceptions_tl
 { \MakeUppercase \emph \textbf } % add here functions for your exceptions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kumaresh_firstletters_head:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
  \tl_if_in:NVTF \c_kumaresh_accents_tl \l_tmpa_tl
   { \kumaresh_firstletter_accent:NNw #1 \q_stop }
   {
    \tl_if_in:NVTF \g_kumaresh_fl_exceptions_tl \l_tmpa_tl
     { \kumaresh_firstletter_exception:Nnw #1 \q_stop }
     { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kumaresh_firstletter_accent:NNw #1 #2 #3 \q_stop
 { #1 {#2} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kumaresh_firstletter_exception:Nnw #1 #2 #3 \q_stop
 { #1 { \kumaresh_firstletters:n { #2 } } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstletters{\"{O}zg\"{u}r \MakeUppercase{This is} a \emph{test of} the \textbf{Emergency Broadcast} System. (This-Test). [for sample]. This \'T.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I wrote this and then forgot.

Comment: Your macro correctly returns nothing, i.e., an empty string, if the argument of `\firstletters` is empty. However, the macro doesn't appear to guard against the possibility that the very first few characters of the string might not be letters. E.g., `\firstletters{.This}` returns `.` rather than `T`.

Comment: This is a general approach that separates each string at spaces and takes the first character. And only one extra step is caring about `-`. If one needs to have more things in account one might want to do `\tl_map_inline:nn { ().; } { \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 } }` and that will remove all those symbols from the equation.

Comment: `\firstletters{\"{O}zg\"{u}r}` produces output as `O` & `\firstletters{{\"{O}}zg\"{u}r}` produces the proper output `Ö`... Any advice on this... –

Comment: @KumareshPS That's simple. I will add in a few minutes. But coping with plain `\firstletters{Özgür}` requires more work.

Comment: @KumareshPS Done. I think it could easily be even generalized to work on `\firstletters{\MakeUppercase{This type} and \emph{that too}}` to output `\MakeUpercase{Tt}a\emph{tt}`. In case you are interested.

Comment: @Manuel: Marvelous! You are a L3 Magician...

Comment: @KumareshPS Added, plus taking care of `([` but you can add whatever to that list.

Answer (score 4):

With a regex we remove everything from a letter to a space or a hyphen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\firstletters}{m}
 {
  \kumaresh_firstletters:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_kumaresh_fl_input_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kumaresh_firstletters:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_kumaresh_fl_input_tl { #1 ~ }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([A-Za-z]).*?[-\s]} { \1 } \l_kumaresh_fl_input_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_kumaresh_fl_input_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\firstletters{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System. This-Test. for sample. This T.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your method doesn't appear to notice that the very first characters of the string may not be alphabetical characters. E.g., if the string is given by "()This ...", your macro returns "()T" rather than "T". Also, it looks like if the string is entirely empty, a single space rather than an empty string is returned.

Comment: @Mico There are no real specifications, so I just assumed letters, spaces and hyphens; it's easy to cope with empty strings if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another LuaLaTeX-based solution. It tests if the string contains any alphabetical characters, and it does nothing if no alphabetical characters are found. It is not assumed that the first character of the string is a letter-type character. The proposed solution can handle non-ASCII-encoded letters such as `ä`, `Ä`, and `Å`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env. and '\luaexec' macro
\begin{luacode}
local i, w , wstring
function fl ( s )
   i = unicode.utf8.find ( s , "%w")
   -- Do nothing if i=="nil", i.e., if 's' doesn't 
   -- contain at least one alphabetical character:
   if i ~= nil then
      -- Pick up the first letter of first word:
      wstring = unicode.utf8.sub ( s , i , i ) 
      s = unicode.utf8.sub ( s , i+1 )
      -- Pick up the first letters of all remaining words:
      for w in unicode.utf8.gmatch ( s , "%W%w" ) do
         wstring = wstring .. unicode.utf8.sub ( w , 2 )
      end
      tex.sprint ( wstring )
   end
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand{\firstletter}[1]{\luaexec{fl(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\firstletter{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System. This-Test. for sample. This T. per se}

% Same string, but with additional non-letter characters
\firstletter{@--?#&$() []<>^_ This is a test of the 
   Emergency    Broadcast System. This--Test. 
   for sample. This T. 
   (per se)}

% Words that start with non-ASCII-encoded characters
\firstletter{$$$ähnlich "öffentlich *übrigens !?<>Äpfel 
   Özgür  ((((^Übung    .ßcheusslich+++ ,===Ångstrom}

\firstletter{!@#$^&*()!@#$^&*()_+-={}[]|\\;<>?Ö} 

% Two strings without any "words"
a\firstletter{"("§$&/)@@=}b\firstletter{}c 

\end{document}
```

Comment: My current template based on LaTeX + dvips...

Comment: @KumareshPS - Is something preventing you from adopting a different work flow?

Answer (score 3):

This takes the earlier insufficient answer you provide (which was mine by the way), and augments it to make the `-` active and equal to a space prior to executing the earlier code.  Thus, the dash-made-space will allow the subsequent letter to be detected as the beginning of a new word.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{index}\setcounter{index}{0}
\catcode`-=\active %
\def-{ }
\catcode`-=12 %
\def\firstletters{\catcode`-=\active \firstlettersX}
\def\firstlettersX#1{%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \edef\nextword{\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\getfirst\nextword\relax%
  }%
  \catcode`-=12 %
}
\def\getfirst#1#2\relax{#1}
\begin{document}
\firstletters{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System. This-Test. for sample. This T.}
- - -Dash restored
\end{document}
```

[image]

An identical approach can be used if you need to capitalize following other punctuation, for example `(` or `[`.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{index}\setcounter{index}{0}
\catcode`-=\active %
\def-{ }
\catcode`-=12 %
\catcode`(=\active %
\def({}
\catcode`(=12 %
\def\newpunct{%
  \catcode`-=\active %
  \catcode`(=\active %
}
\def\oldpunct{%
  \catcode`-=12 %
  \catcode`(=12 %
}
\def\firstletters{\newpunct\firstlettersX}
\def\firstlettersX#1{%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \edef\nextword{\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\getfirst\nextword\relax\relax%
  }%
  \oldpunct%
}
\def\getfirst#1#2\relax{#1}
\begin{document}
\firstletters{This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System (per se). 
    This-Test. for sample. This T.}
- - -Dash restored (and paren too)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your methods appear not to pick up the possibility that the very first character of the string needn't be a letter, and they crash if the first character is a space. :-(

Comment: @Mico as to the leading space issue, I just edited to add an extra `\relax` in the code \getfirst\nextword\relax\relax` which fixes that issue.  As to the first problem with non-alphabetic lead characters, that is the exact problem that *is* addressed by this solution.  I have shown how to do it with dashes and a left paren... other characters can be added, as well.